# Pull documents from Manilla into Evernote

Tags: evernote, document-management

I have accounts at [Manilla](http://manilla.com/) and [Evernote](http://evernote.com/).  I currently scan in all of my mail and store it in Evernote.  For paperless bills, almost all of them get pulled into my Manilla account. Right now, I have to download each document from Manilla and then import it into Evernote.

I looked into [If This Than That](http://ifttt.com/) but there wasn't a Manilla channel.  I can't find any evidence that Manilla has an API, so that is probably the reason.

Is there a way **automatically** to copy the documents from Manilla into Evernote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at a product called [FileThis](http://www.filethis.com). It fetches your documents and delivers them to the destination of your choice, including Dropbox and Evernote.

For full disclosure, I work at FileThis. Sounds like we do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I see my question was too specific.  What I should have asked is "How do I get my bills/statements automatically imported into Evernote".  I appreciate the recommendation for FileThis, and just from looking at the front page, this appears to be exactly what I'm looking for!